# How to convert days to minutes

Tags: postgresql

Need to convert the output from below to minutes:

example query:

```
SELECT 
  avg(date - create_date)
FROM x
```

example outputs - need to be converted into minutes:

```
20 days 24:22:59.328877
1 day 16:30:18.131138
5 days 16:46:54.355619
```

Comment: hi, Phil, this is exactly the example output: <20 days 24:22:59.328877> so days/hours/minutes etc - I need to convert the whole thing to minutes. I think I found a solution just now: EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM avg(date - create_date)) - it gives the output in seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract `epoch` to get seconds, then divide by 60:

```
select
    extract(epoch from avg(date - create_date)) / 60 as avg_minutes
```